# Finding the number of files on a btrfs system without using find

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

Typically I'd use `df -i` to get a good estimate based on the number of inodes used. Unfortunately, btrfs does not seem to have inodes (I could be wrong here), and `df -i` reports the following:

```
/dev/xvdf1             0     0         0     - /output
```

Unfortunately, I have a huge amount of files on this file system, and a script running that's basically utilizing all of the IO. Does btrfs track the number of files in some other way? Is there an easy way to get an estimate of the number of files on the filesystem without using `find`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be as simple as you're looking for, but `rsync` will give you that info, and it's techincally not `find`.

`rsync -an --stats /path/to/btrfs /empty/dir`

The `n` option makes it a dry run so it won't copy anything, and the `--stats` should give you stats like the number of files/directories, and the total size.